# time.sleep makes tkinter crash is there anything else i can use

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm making a case opener based on CS:GO's odds and I'm trying to make an animation of some sort using random number generation.

Example:

```
while x <10:
        openr = random.randint (0,10000)
        #blue
        if openr < 7992:
            anim_txt_5 = anim_txt_4
            anim_txt_4 = anim_txt_3
            anim_txt_3 = anim_txt_2
            anim_txt_2 = anim_txt_1
            anim_txt_1 = " Mil Spec "

            anim_col_5 = anim_col_4
            anim_col_4 = anim_col_3
            anim_col_3 = anim_col_2
            anim_col_2 = anim_col_1
            anim_col_1 = 'blue'
            x+= 1
            z*= 2
            anim_1.config(text = anim_txt_5, bg = anim_col_5)
            anim_2.config(text = anim_txt_4, bg = anim_col_4)
            anim_3.config(text = anim_txt_3, bg = anim_col_3)
            anim_4.config(text = anim_txt_2, bg = anim_col_2)
            anim_5.config(text = anim_txt_1, bg = anim_col_1)
```

But if I add `time.sleep()` to make the animation seem like its rolling tkinter just crashes. So is there anything else I can use to make it wait. x just says how many times its gonna do the animation and z is what the time is going to be but I haven't set up the right multiplication yet to make it right.

all the code

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.title ('not stonks simulator')
root.resizable (480, 480)

#variabales for results
list_col_1 = 'light grey'
list_col_2 = 'light grey'
list_col_3 = 'light grey'
list_col_4 = 'light grey'
list_col_5 = 'light grey'
list_1 = " "
list_2 = " "
list_3 = " "
list_4 = " "
list_5 = " "

#variables for opening animation
x = 0
z = .01
anim_col_1 = 'grey'
anim_col_2 = 'grey'
anim_col_3 = 'grey'
anim_col_4 = 'grey'
anim_col_5 = 'grey'
anim_txt_1 = "       "
anim_txt_2 = "       "
anim_txt_3 = "       "
anim_txt_4 = "       "
anim_txt_5 = "       "

def opener():
    global list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5, list_col_1, list_col_2, list_col_3, list_col_4, list_col_5, x, z, anim_col_1, anim_col_2, anim_col_3, anim_col_4, anim_col_5, anim_txt_1, anim_txt_2, anim_txt_3,anim_txt_4, anim_txt_5
    num = random.randint(0,10000)
    x = 0
    #opening animation thing
    while x <10:
        openr = random.randint (0,10000)
        #blue
        if openr < 7992:
            anim_txt_5 = anim_txt_4
            anim_txt_4 = anim_txt_3
            anim_txt_3 = anim_txt_2
            anim_txt_2 = anim_txt_1
            anim_txt_1 = " Mil Spec "

            anim_col_5 = anim_col_4
            anim_col_4 = anim_col_3
            anim_col_3 = anim_col_2
            anim_col_2 = anim_col_1
            anim_col_1 = 'blue'
            x+= 1
            z*= 2
            anim_1.config(text = anim_txt_5, bg = anim_col_5)
            anim_2.config(text = anim_txt_4, bg = anim_col_4)
            anim_3.config(text = anim_txt_3, bg = anim_col_3)
            anim_4.config(text = anim_txt_2, bg = anim_col_2)
            anim_5.config(text = anim_txt_1, bg = anim_col_1)
            #purple
        if openr >= 9590 and num <= 9909:
            anim_txt_5 = anim_txt_4
            anim_txt_4 = anim_txt_3
            anim_txt_3 = anim_txt_2
            anim_txt_2 = anim_txt_1
            anim_txt_1 = "Restricted"

            anim_col_5 = anim_col_4
            anim_col_4 = anim_col_3
            anim_col_3 = anim_col_2
            anim_col_2 = anim_col_1
            anim_col_1 = 'purple'

            x += 1
            z *= 2
            anim_1.config(text=anim_txt_5, bg=anim_col_5)
            anim_2.config(text=anim_txt_4, bg=anim_col_4)
            anim_3.config(text=anim_txt_3, bg=anim_col_3)
            anim_4.config(text=anim_txt_2, bg=anim_col_2)
            anim_5.config(text=anim_txt_1, bg=anim_col_1)

        #pink
        if openr >= 9909 and num <= 9973:
            anim_txt_5 = anim_txt_4
            anim_txt_4 = anim_txt_3
            anim_txt_3 = anim_txt_2
            anim_txt_2 = anim_txt_1
            anim_txt_1 = "Classified"

            anim_col_5 = anim_col_4
            anim_col_4 = anim_col_3
            anim_col_3 = anim_col_2
            anim_col_2 = anim_col_1
            anim_col_1 = 'pink'

            x += 1
            z *= 2

            anim_1.config(text=anim_txt_5, bg=anim_col_5)
            anim_2.config(text=anim_txt_4, bg=anim_col_4)
            anim_3.config(text=anim_txt_3, bg=anim_col_3)
            anim_4.config(text=anim_txt_2, bg=anim_col_2)
            anim_5.config(text=anim_txt_1, bg=anim_col_1)

        #red
        if openr >= 9909 and num <= 9973:
            anim_txt_5 = anim_txt_4
            anim_txt_4 = anim_txt_3
            anim_txt_3 = anim_txt_2
            anim_txt_2 = anim_txt_1
            anim_txt_1 = "  Covert  "

            anim_col_5 = anim_col_4
            anim_col_4 = anim_col_3
            anim_col_3 = anim_col_2
            anim_col_2 = anim_col_1
            anim_col_1 = 'red'

            x += 1
            z *= 2

            anim_1.config(text=anim_txt_5, bg=anim_col_5)
            anim_2.config(text=anim_txt_4, bg=anim_col_4)
            anim_3.config(text=anim_txt_3, bg=anim_col_3)
            anim_4.config(text=anim_txt_2, bg=anim_col_2)
            anim_5.config(text=anim_txt_1, bg=anim_col_1)

        #yellow
        if openr >= 9973 and num <= 10000:
            anim_txt_5 = anim_txt_4
            anim_txt_4 = anim_txt_3
            anim_txt_3 = anim_txt_2
            anim_txt_2 = anim_txt_1
            anim_txt_1 = "  Knife   "

            anim_col_5 = anim_col_4
            anim_col_4 = anim_col_3
            anim_col_3 = anim_col_2
            anim_col_2 = anim_col_1
            anim_col_1 = 'yellow'

            x += 1
            z *= 2

            anim_1.config(text=anim_txt_5, bg=anim_col_5)
            anim_2.config(text=anim_txt_4, bg=anim_col_4)
            anim_3.config(text=anim_txt_3, bg=anim_col_3)
            anim_4.config(text=anim_txt_2, bg=anim_col_2)
            anim_5.config(text=anim_txt_1, bg=anim_col_1)
    if x > 100:
      #blue
      if num < 7992:
        label_3.config(text="Mil Spec", bg='blue')

        #names for list
        list_5 = list_4
        list_4 = list_3
        list_3 = list_2
        list_2 = list_1
        list_1 = "Mil Spec"

        #colors for list
        list_col_5 = list_col_4
        list_col_4 = list_col_3
        list_col_3 = list_col_2
        list_col_2 = list_col_1
        list_col_1 = 'blue'

        #updating labels
        label_4.config(text=list_1, bg=list_col_1)
        label_5.config(text=list_2, bg=list_col_2)
        label_6.config(text=list_3, bg=list_col_3)
        label_7.config(text=list_4, bg=list_col_4)
        label_8.config(text=list_5, bg=list_col_5)

        #purple
        if num >= 7992 and num <= 9590:
          label_3.config(text="Restricted", bg='purple')
          #names for list
          list_5 = list_4
          list_4 = list_3
          list_3 = list_2
          list_2 = list_1
          list_1 = "Restricted"

          #list for colors
          lsit_col_5 = list_col_4
          lsit_col_4 = list_col_3
          lsit_col_3 = list_col_2
          lsit_col_2 = list_col_1
          list_col_1 = 'purple'

        #updating labels
        label_4.config(text=list_1, bg=list_col_1)
        label_5.config(text=list_2, bg=list_col_2)
        label_6.config(text=list_3, bg=list_col_3)
        label_7.config(text=list_4, bg=list_col_4)
        label_8.config(text=list_5, bg=list_col_5)

      #pink
      if num >= 9590 and num <= 9909:
        label_3.config(text="Classified", bg= 'pink')

        #names for list
        list_5 = list_4
        list_4 = list_3
        list_3 = list_2
        list_2 = list_1

        #colors for list
        list_1 = "Classified"
        lsit_col_5 = list_col_4
        lsit_col_4 = list_col_3
        lsit_col_3 = list_col_2
        lsit_col_2 = list_col_1
        list_col_1 = 'pink'

        # updating labels
        label_4.config(text=list_1, bg=list_col_1)
        label_5.config(text=list_2, bg=list_col_2)
        label_6.config(text=list_3, bg=list_col_3)
        label_7.config(text=list_4, bg=list_col_4)
        label_8.config(text=list_5, bg=list_col_5)

      #red
      if num >= 9909 and num <= 9973:
        label_3.config(text="Covert", bg='red')

        #names for list
        list_5 = list_4
        list_4 = list_3
        list_3 = list_2
        list_2 = list_1
        list_1 = "Covert"

        #colors for list
        lsit_col_5 = list_col_4
        lsit_col_4 = list_col_3
        lsit_col_3 = list_col_2
        lsit_col_2 = list_col_1
        list_col_1 = 'red'

        # updating labels
        label_4.config(text=list_1, bg=list_col_1)
        label_5.config(text=list_2, bg=list_col_2)
        label_6.config(text=list_3, bg=list_col_3)
        label_7.config(text=list_4, bg=list_col_4)
        label_8.config(text=list_5, bg=list_col_5)

      #knife
      if num >= 9973 and num <= 10000:
        label_3.config(text="Exceedingly Rare", bg='yellow')

        #names for list
        list_5 = list_4
        list_4 = list_3
        list_3 = list_2
        list_2 = list_1
        list_1 = "Exceedingly Rare"

        #colors for list
        lsit_col_5 = list_col_4
        lsit_col_4 = list_col_3
        lsit_col_3 = list_col_2
        lsit_col_2 = list_col_1
        list_col_1 = 'yellow'

        # updating labels
        label_4.config(text=list_1, bg=list_col_1)
        label_5.config(text=list_2, bg=list_col_2)
        label_6.config(text=list_3, bg=list_col_3)
        label_7.config(text=list_4, bg=list_col_4)
        label_8.config(text=list_5, bg=list_col_5)
      else:
          pass
    else:
        pass


#labels
label_1 = tk.Label(root,  text = "Case Opener Made by Storm")
label_2 = tk.Label(root, text = "You opened: ")
label_3 = tk.Label(root, text = "       ")
label_4 = tk.Label(root)
label_5 = tk.Label(root)
label_6 = tk.Label(root)
label_7 = tk.Label(root)
label_8 = tk.Label(root)
label_9 = tk.Label(root, text = "Last opened:")

#labels for opening animation
anim_1 = tk.Label (root)
anim_2 = tk.Label (root)
anim_3 = tk.Label (root)
anim_4 = tk.Label (root)
anim_5 = tk.Label (root)

#button
Button_1 =tk.Button (text =  "click to open",command = opener)

#placements for main elements
#label_1.grid (row = 0, column = 0)
label_2.grid (row = 2, column = 0)
label_3.grid (row = 2, column = 1)

#placements for list of recieved items
label_4.grid (row = 2, column = 7)
label_5.grid (row = 3, column = 7)
label_6.grid (row = 4, column = 7)
label_7.grid (row = 5, column = 7)
label_8.grid (row = 6, column = 7)
label_9.grid (row = 0, column = 7)

#placements for animation labels
anim_1.grid (row =1, column =1)
anim_2.grid (row =1, column =2)
anim_3.grid (row =1, column =3)
anim_4.grid (row =1, column =4)
anim_5.grid (row =1, column =5)


#placement for opener button
Button_1.grid (row = 2, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
´´´
```

Comment: `after(ms,func)` can be used

Comment: where would i need to put it in?

Comment: Its not sure what your trying to do without an example that even we can copy paste and run.

Comment: ok let me update the post

Comment: It doesn't make the app crash, it does exactly what it says: it puts the app to sleep. Sleeping isn't crashing.

Comment: yeah i know its supposed to make it sleep for specific amount of time but when i try to use it it just crashes anyway like if i it to time.sleep(1) it doesnt sleep for 1 second and then continues. the entire thing freezes for a good bit and then crashes

Comment: Yes it freezes, it wont crash, you wont be able to interact with it for 1 second. But copying and pasting your code, I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: oh then i see i didnt know it makes so you can interact with it. that might help me solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, but I believe I have the answer. @Cool Cloud is correct that after(ms, func) will wait to execute a specific command without slowing down other tkinter functionality. I have witnessed this over the past week building my first Tkinter application :)

Whenever you think you want to use time.sleep(s), use instead:

```
root.after(ms, func)
```